# Graph coloring: Why is $f(m) \leq \sqrt{m}$?

Tags: graph-theory, coloring

I am supposed to prove that a graph with $m = |E|$ edges is colored by at most

$$\lceil\sqrt{2m}\rceil$$

colors by a greedy algorithm.

We were given this recursive formula:

$$f(1) = 2$$
$$f(m) \leq f(m-k) + 1$$

where $k$ is the sum of the degrees of the nodes with color 1.

I am trying to solve this for hours and I still have no idea how to get to the result.

Any hints from your side?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A greedy algorithm colors a graph of max degree $\Delta$ in at most $\Delta +1 $ colors.

The max degree of a graph with $n$ vertices is $n-1$. So such a graph will take $n$ colors. So we need to solve for $n$ and this will be our upper bound.

Further, a graph with $n$ vertices has at most $\frac{n(n-1)}{2}$ edges (equality with the $n$-complete graph). Now lets work backwards.

$$m = \frac{n(n-1)}{2}$$
We need to check that $$n \leq \lceil \sqrt{2m} \rceil$$
$$n \leq \left\lceil \sqrt {2 \frac{n(n-1)}{2}} \right\rceil$$
$$n \leq \left\lceil \sqrt {n(n-1)} \right\rceil$$
and this holds for $n>1$ we are done.

Comment: The basic idea that we need $\lceil \sqrt{2m} \rceil$ colors for a complete graph with $m = \binom n2$ edges is correct, but the rest of your argument is wrong. You are assuming for no reason at all that the max number of colors has to be the number of vertices (this is false in general). Then you are assuming without justification that all $\frac{n(n-1)}{2}$ edges have to be present to get $n$ colors (this is true, but you haven't proven it).

Comment: I suppose it would be more accurate to claim that the upper bound for the maximum number of colors is $n$. It seems obvious that the $n$-complete graph (which has $\frac{n(n-1)}{2}$ edges) is the worst case and will require all $n$ colors.

Comment: It doesn't seem obvious to me that there isn't another graph $G$ with $\chi(G)=n$ that has more than $n$ vertices but fewer than $\frac{n(n-1)}{2}$ edges. It is true that there is no such graph - but it requires proof.